# Rebind emacs "C-d" to delete word

Tags: emacs, keymapping

I have tried several different ways of doing this, and none have been successful. I want to switch the M-d and C-d functionality (delete word, delete char) respectively while working in c++ files.

Can someone please lend me a hand?

Comment: Even though this question has already been answered correctly, I just would like to comment that you might consider leaving the keybindings the way they are. There's no objective advantage for switching them, and if you train your muscle memory -- which doesn't take very long at all! -- you'll get a consistent behavior in Emacs independent of the major mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-initialization-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key c++-mode-map "\C-d" 'kill-word)
            (define-key c++-mode-map "\M-d" 'c-electric-delete-forward)))
```

From [CC Hooks - CC Mode Manulal](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/CC-Hooks.html):

> Variable: **c-initialization-hook**
>
> Hook run only once per Emacs session, when CC Mode is initialized. This is a good place to change key bindings (or add new ones) in any of the CC Mode key maps. See [Sample .emacs File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Sample-_002eemacs-File.html#Sample-_002eemacs-File).

Comment: This does the job but has two problems. First you run the same code everytime you open a new buffer with C++. This kind of code is better run once and for all for the C++ mode in general. Second it does not use `kbd` and is therefore less readable/more error prone.

Comment: @NicolasDudebout Thank you for your comment. I've updated my post so that it uses `c-initialization-hook`, which is executed only once per Emacs session, instead of `c++-mode-hook`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(eval-after-load "cc-mode"
  '(progn
     (define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-d") 'kill-word)
     (define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "M-d") 'delete-char)))
```